# method execution after its being called instead of when its called

Tags: c#

I am trying to call Method 1,2,3 but not execute its content until it gets execute command. because some other code might fail before execute that will needed to revert the action but if we run the Method 1,2,3 before "SPECIAL CODE" its already too late to revert it back.

how do I design this as clean as possible?

```
public class FooService
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        // RUN A
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        // RUN B
    }

    public void Method3()
    {
        // RUN C
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        // Execute all methods that being called
    }
}

public class BooService
{
    public void Something()
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        if (r.NextBool())
            FooService.Method1();

        if (r.NextBool())
            FooService.Method2();

        if (r.NextBool())
            FooService.Method3();

        //SOME SPECIAL CODE HERE

        FooService.Execute();
    }
}
```

**T.S. Solution**

```
public class FooService
{
    static List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

    public static void Method1()
    {
        if (!actions.Contains(FooService.Method1))
            actions.Add(FooService.Method1);
        else
        {
            // RUN A
        }
    }

    public static void Method2()
    {
        if (!actions.Contains(FooService.Method2))
            actions.Add(FooService.Method2);
        else
        {
            // RUN B
        }
    }

    public static void Method3()
    {
        if (!actions.Contains(FooService.Method2))
            actions.Add(FooService.Method2);
        else
        {
            // RUN C
        }
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        actions.ForEach(x => x.Invoke());
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is possible why not execute one/some/n of those methods 1,2,3 *after* the dependent code executes? Just swap the position of the code blocks, that would be the simplest way to go about it.

Comment: because there are other codes work with Method1,2,3 which I removed to simplify. those codes changes values that "SPECIAL CODE" uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have will only make sense if you want let some "SPECIAL CODE" execute your method. For example, your code with some modifications

```cs
public class BooService
{
    public void Something()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        var actions = new List<Action>();

        if (r.NextBool())
            actions.Add(FooService.Method1);

        if (r.NextBool())
            actions.Add(FooService.Method2);

        if (r.NextBool())
            actions.Add(FooService.Method3);

        //SOME SPECIAL CODE HERE
        SomeOtherClass.Execute(actions);
        
    }
}
```

In this case your `SomeOtherClass` gets the list of callbacks it needs to execute while decision, **which** code it must execute is made in the different class.

If the execution takes place in the same method as decision, then just use `if/switch`. However, sometimes you can have a large factory and you can call `a.Invoke()` or just `a()`

Comment: If I can burry this action list into FooService that might work

Comment: I changed your answer and added to the main

Comment: @Mert Well, yes. without all the specifics it is hard to give perfect answer. I tried to be minimalistic here , just to show the "ways". There is another answer that goes even further on what you can do with delegates and may be even expression trees. I only wanted to point that method sequence can be "recorded" and executed later.

Answer (score 2):

Using named `ValueTuple` and `params` you can create an "Executor" that scales to any number of calls, would be easy to maintain, and whose usage would lead to concise code. Consider this implementation,

```
public static class Executor
{
    public static void ExecuteMethods(Action specialCode, params (Func<bool> Predicate, Action Action)[] actions)
    {
        specialCode();

        // no Execute() needed... this IS the execution
        foreach (var pair in actions)
            if (pair.Predicate())
                pair.Action();
    }    
}
```

which gives this concise code at the callsite,

```
Random r = new Random();
Executor.Execute(
    () =>
    {
        // SOME SPECIAL CODE HERE
    },
    (() => r.NextBool(), FooService.Method1),
    (() => r.NextBool(), FooService.Method2),
    (() => r.NextBool(), FooService.Method3));
```

If you need the predicates evaluated before SPECIAL CODE, change `ExecuteMethods` to

```
public static void ExecuteMethods(Action specialCode, params (Func<bool> Predicate, Action Action)[] actions)
{
    var preEvaluatedPredicates = actions
        .Select(x => (x.Predicate() Predicate, x.Action Action)
        .ToList();

    specialCode();

    foreach (var pair in preEvaluatedPredicates)
        if (pair.Predicate)
            pair.Action();
}
```

or change the signature, implementation, and call to

```
public static void ExecuteMethods(Action specialCode, params (bool Predicate, Action Action)[] actions)
{
    specialCode();

    foreach (var pair in actions)
        if (pair.Predicate)
            pair.Action();
}

...

Random r = new Random();
Executor.Execute(
    () =>
    {
        // SOME SPECIAL CODE HERE
    },
    (r.NextBool(), FooService.Method1),
    (r.NextBool(), FooService.Method2),
    (r.NextBool(), FooService.Method3));
```

If you need to change the order, specifically when to run `specialCode()`, just move it to where you need it in `ExecuteMethods`.

Comment: you answer is very good too. been an educational experience

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe do like this. Represent all actions as objects, that implement a single interface. Then `FooService.Method1` and similar methods would "queue" corresponding methods (meaining that these action objects would be stored in some collection, and not yet executed). Then, when executing, every action would be executed in order

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IFooServiceMethod {
    bool Run(FooService service);
}
public class FooServiceMethod1 : IFooServiceMethod {
    bool IFooServiceMethod.Run(FooService service)
    {
        // RUN A
        return true;
    }
}
public class FooServiceMethod2 : IFooServiceMethod {
    bool IFooServiceMethod.Run(FooService service)
    {
        // RUN B
        return true;
    }
}
public class FooService
{
    public void Method1() 
    {
        // just queue a method, not execute it yet
        _methodsChain.Add(new FooServiceMethod1());
    }
    
    public void Method2() 
    {
        _methodsChain.Add(new FooServiceMethod2());
    }
    
    public void Execute()
    {
        // execute everything queued
        _methodsChain.ForEach(method => method.Run(this));
    }
    
    List<IFooServiceMethod> _methodsChain = new List<IFooServiceMethod>(); 
    
}
```